# Парсинг ответов с сайта

Tags: java, парсер

Есть сайт, который по коду выдает данные (ответы). Т.е., в форму поиска вписывается код, нажимается Enter или кнопка поиска, и сайт выдает текст в табличке.

До этого никогда парсингом с сайтов не занимался, только писал на java.

Как реализовать такую программу?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Вы можете использовать библиотеку [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), которая позволяет загружать нужную web-страницу/файл и искать/извлекать данные с использованием `css` селекторов, либо стандартным обходом `DOM`.

Для заполнения формы и получения результатов запроса необходимо получить адрес запроса и его параметры, затем просто эмулировать запрос с нужными параметрами. Например:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
    .data("action", "login")
    .data("user", "user")
    .data("password", "123456")
    .post();
```

Comment: Или просто используйте URLConnection и пишите в него заголовки (Post.USER AGENT):) +не забудьте куко класс прилипить.

Answer (score 2):

1. Получаешь html текст сайта в `String` (например, `post` или `get` запросом)
2. Используешь `str.substring` `str.indexOf` для получение нужного текста из html

В общем, если ответ не `json` или не `xml`, то просто работай со строками. Если ответ в `json`, то найди какую-нибудь библиотеку для парсинга `json`

Comment: Да, когда я получу данные, я уже придумаю как их обработать. Вопрос скорее заключается в том, как автоматизировать ввод кодов и нажатие enter (кнопки поиск) для того чтобы получить эти данные. Как объяснить java что нужно вписать код в окно поиска и "нажать Enter"?

Comment: Код не надо вводить в поля в привычном для вас понимании. Любая информация отправляется параметрами `get` и `post`. Если не знаете, что такое `<form>` в html, почитайте. Думаю, это вам поможет

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте что-то подобное:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url");

List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", "1111"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters, "UTF-8"));

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял тебе нежно знать как забрать от них данные.

По сути тебе придётся профайлером посмотреть какой запрос возвращает ответ на страницу сайта и симулировать его.

В большинство поисков если они открыты для гугла то после нажатия на Интер происходит редирект на другую страницу с параметрами запроса. Вот тебе придётся и генерировать этот урл и забирать по нему данные.